# Refrain Django Models from creating an object after a specific count of that object in db is reached, for a specific user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to have a method to somehow show an error/prompt to the front end (could be json response), whenever user tries to add an object, in my case, 1 user cannot have more than 50 tasks stored inside the db, my db model is simple, it's just a task model, and a user model, each task has a foreign key user_id. I was doing it in golang-gorm using hooks, is there any similar method in Django to do so efficiently?

Comment: Can you share the form (and view) where you aim to add the tasks to a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the clean method of your `Task` model in order to raise a `ValidationError` if the related user already has 50 tasks.

Something like this :

```
class Task(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeyKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')

   def clean(self):
       if self.user.tasks.count() >= 50:
           raise ValidationError('User cannot have more than 50 tasks')
```

Comment: I think this won't work since the `clean` method is called when the values are updated and *before* the object is saved by the form. But a many-to-many field is updated *after* the model object has been saved. So the check is "too early".

Comment: You likely can check this in the form such that this is validated *before* saving the object.